# Counting solutions to a five-variable equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How many solutions (using only nonnegative integers) are there to the equation
>   $$x_1+ x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 31\;?$$

Comment: Where did you come across this problem, and how would you approach solving it?

Comment: Please see Stars and Bars (combinatorics, Wikipedia) or the many answers on MSE that discuss Stars and Bars.